# Wordpress featured image url changes when echoed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this snippet of code in my single.php template. It get's the url of the featured image so I can use it as a background image as apposed to using get_post_thumbnail() which outputs the complete image tag.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
}
```

Here is where things get strange.

If I var_dump the result I get one output and when I echo I get another.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
  $heroimage = $featured_image[0];
  echo ($heroimage); // outputs /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/img-social-tweet-dec11.png
  var_dump($heroimage); // outputs string(54) "http://assets.d2l.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/img-social-tweet-dec11.png"
  echo ($heroimage); // outputs http://assets.d2l.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/img-social-tweet-dec11.png 
  echo ($heroimage); // outputs /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/img-social-tweet-dec11.png 
}
```

The echo that immediately follows the var dump is what I am expecting. The others are stripping out the domain name.

Comment: What is `$heroimage` — not just a string (please check)?

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array, and the the string value of the image url comes back as the first element in that array. For the purpose of my test I just simply saved $featured_image[0] into a new variable $heroimage. However, I could replace all instances of $heroimage in the code with $featured_image[0], and I get the same results.

Comment: So a get_class($heroimage) would generate an error?

Comment: Yes. Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Comment: Ok. What an odd error, please post of you find more clues